# three.js - improve performance (FPS) using CanvasRenderer

Tags: javascript, json, html5-canvas, three.js

I've a tube geometry.
18738 points in JSON file. Tube is built with 2000 points (taking every 9th point into consideration).
Tube has 2000 segments (mandatory), 12 faces on each segment, applied color to each face.

When I render the model with `THREE.WebGLRenderer` on desktop browser, the FPS is between 54-60. 
When I render the same model with `THREE.CanvasRenderer` on desktop browser, the FPS is 1-2.

I've to run this model on iPad. So I need to use `THREE.CanvasRenderer`. If I decrease the number of segments the FPS will increase but 2000 segments is a necessary requirement.

JSON file has following structure:

```
{"id":"0",
"r30" :"5.247","r60" :"5.088","r90" :"4.77","r120" :"5.724","r150" :"5.83","r180" :"5.459","r210" :"5.194","r240" :"5.035","r270" :"5.247","r300" :"5.565","r330" :"5.618","md":"20","point" :new THREE.Vector3(0,0,20)}
```

Similar way I've 18738 points and plotting every 9th point to built a tube.

```
tubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(tube, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    shading: THREE.FlatShading,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    wireframe: false,
    transparent: false,
    vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,
    overdraw: false
}));​
```

**How do I improve the performance of FPS using `THREE.CanvasRenderer` ?**

r53

Comment: I know this isn't really related to your question, but if you've got `new THREE.Vector3(0,0,20)` in your "JSON" file, you aren't using JSON.  As far as relating to your question, the only way I could think to increase speed is to use some sort of alternate representation (what that would be, I wouldn't know, especially with your "must have 2000 segments" comment).

Comment: Actually I've stored the point co-ordinates and other values in JSON object so that once I parse the object I can have all the required properties for the 3d model. And yes 2000 segments is mandatory requirement.-@JayC

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, `CanvasRenderer` is not able to deal with such numbers. Even less on an iPad.

Comment: Is there any way I can run this model using `CanvasRenderer`? If there is no way then how do I increase the performance using `WebGLRenderer` on android tablet ?-@mrdoob

Comment: Can `THREE.MeshFaceMaterial` improve the performance with `CanvasRenderer` ?-@mrdoob